# Manipulating one of several SqlDataSource query results before displaying them all in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, entity-framework-6, sqldatatypes

Using the following code as an example, how would I go about changing the customer IP from a `binary[4]` datatype from SQL to a quad IP address and display that result as a string in a gridview? All other columns show correctly, but the Customer IP currently shows as `System.Byte[]`

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
     datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
     autogeneratecolumns="false"
     autogenerateeditbutton="true"
     allowpaging="true" 
     datakeynames="CustomerID"  
     runat="server">

    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerIP" readonly="true" headertext="Customer IP"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" convertemptystringtonull="true" headertext="Customer Name"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" convertemptystringtonull="true" headertext="Address"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="City" convertemptystringtonull="true" headertext="City"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" convertemptystringtonull="true" headertext="ZIP Code"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Country" convertemptystringtonull="true" headertext="Country"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>

<asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSqlDataSource"  
     selectcommand="Select [CustomerIP], [CompanyName], [Address], [City], [PostalCode], [Country] From [Customers]"
     updatecommand="Update Customers Set CompanyName=@CompanyName, Address=@Address, City=@City, PostalCode=@PostalCode, Country=@Country Where (CustomerIP = @CustomerIP)"
     connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString%>"
     runat="server">
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Comment: I can't say for sure this is the best or easiest way, but with the [DataBound event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/custom-formatting-based-upon-data-cs#step-3-formatting-the-unitprice-value-in-the-detailsview) you have chance to alter the value of a cell. I assume you can figure out how to convert 4 bytes into 4 integers?

Comment: I went a different direction with this.  I'm just getting my feet wet with C#/SQL/Entity Framework 6 and didn't realize I needed to bind my datasource to the EF instead of directly to SQL.  The OnRowDatabound event is what I'll use to edit.